# Regular expression: Each occurence of word where no special character is preceding

Tags: regex, matlab

I really can't get a regular expression to work for the following situation. I'm basically parsing some code files. I want to match each occurence of a word that is not preceded and followed by an alphanumeric character but only if there is no special character preceding this occurence. To make this more clearly an example:

Word to match: `test_word`

Special character: `%`

Example text with in square brackets the number of matches I want:

```
This is some example text                    [0]
(v, c) = test_word                           [1]
test_word(a,b)                               [1]
% a = test_word(b);                          [0]
test_word                                    [1]
a = test_word(d); b = test_word(c);          [2]
a = test_word; % b = test_word;              [1]
d = this_test_word(c)                        [0]
```

With the simple expression: `\Wtest_word\W`  I get to match each occurence of `test_word` regardless what comes beforehand. So I tried the expression

```
(?m)^([^%\n]*?\W)test_word(\W[^\n]*?)$
```

This works for all but the one case with two occurences. I just cannot get this one to work. I tried with lookaround assertions but I'm really stuck here.

Thank you a lot for your help!

If it matters I'm working in Matlab.

Comment: You can test for one or the other, but not both simultaneously in matlab. `\btest_word\b` will get all occurrences of `test_word` that are not preceded or followed by a word character, but you can't test against the *special character*. Matlab doesn't support the tokens `\K` or `\G` or variable width lookbehinds, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Matlab regex does not support variable width lookbehind, and no `\G` anchor is supported, thus, you can't use a plain regex pattern. No idea if a dynamic expression `(??expr)` can help here.

Comment: The only thing you can possibly do is `^[^%\n]*?\b(test_word)\b` and just add a bunch of `(?:[^%\n]*?\b(test_word)\b)?`, but that's ugly, messy and I would definitely steer you away from that option.

Comment: While not familiar with matlab, I would recommend running regex replace once to strip comments (`%.*`) and then trivially search for `\Wtest_word\W` on the cleaned text

Comment: The issue with stripping is I´m doing this to replace the test_word with another. Stripping means I have a very cumbersome reconstruction process ahead which I´m not even sure would be possible.

Comment: Is your actual application to parse Matlab code?

Comment: Yes I`m trying to parse matlab code to automatically rename function calls

Comment: You can do it with Python PyPi regex module or .NET regex using `(?<!%.*)\btest_word\b`. Not with Matlab regex.